# configure error "OpenSSL has unsupported dynamic loading" when building bind9

Tags: openssl, bind, build

When trying to build bind from sources, `./configure` fails with the following output:

```
checking for OpenSSL library... using OpenSSL from /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include
checking whether linking with OpenSSL works... yes
checking whether linking with OpenSSL requires -ldl... unknown
configure: error: OpenSSL has unsupported dynamic loading
```

I have OpenSSL 1.1.0e in /usr/local and I'm trying to build bind 9.11.0-P3.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that bind does not yet support OpenSSL 1.1 (see [OPenssl 1.1 and Bind](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2016-August/097382.html) on bind-users mailing list). Installing OpenSSL 1.0.2k and compiling against it solved my issue.